# Easier way to click button in nested divs with Watir?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm new to Watir and I'm trying to click the following login button:

```
<div class="container login" style="display: table;">
    <div class="left">
    <div class="right">
        <div class="joinbox">
            <form id="form_login" class="hidden-submit" method="post">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="left">
                    <div class="mid">
                    <div class="right">
                       <a class="button button-red submit" href="#">Log In</a>
                    ...
```

So far I'm able to access this button by going through every nested div:

```
b.div(:class, "container login").div(:class, "right").div(:class, "joinbox")......
```

and so on. Is this really the best way to access this button? I assume I'm missing something. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: work with the element itself if there is an easy unique identifier.  otherwise work with the lowest level 'container' such as a div or span you can easily identify and then specify the link within that element  e.g.  `browser.div(:how, what).link.click`

Comment: Am I missing something too, or can you not just go b.button(:value=>'Submit')? I'm on watir-webdriver now, maybe I've forgotten something.

Comment: @kinofrost: you could if there was such a button on the page, but in this case it is a link

Comment: @ŽeljkoFilipin I have spotted my mistake, I see the button (link) he's on about now, I was looking too far up the tree. Ignore me! :)

Answer (score 2):

If there is only one link (that looks like a button) with text `Log In` on the page, try this:

```
browser.a(:text => "Log In").click
```

You could also use `class` attribute:

```
browser.a(:class => "button button-red submit").click
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried both methods and both of them returned UknownObjectException: unable to locate element.

FWIW, I am using ruby 1.9.3 and watir-webdriver 0.3.9 on os x lion with firefox.

Comment: @carlmonday on your page it's not really a button, but a link. Željko gave you the right answer as a general statement, but to be specific to your page it would be: browser.link(:text => "Log In") or browser.link(:class => "button button-red submit").

Comment: Really, now that I took a better look, it is really a link, not a button. I will fix the code in my answer. Thanks @adamreed. :)

Comment: Button can be used to work with button elements and a subset of 'input' elements that take the appearance of a button.  Sometimes links can look like buttons, particularly if an image is provided via CSS (often a 'background image' controlled by the class of the element), but despite what they look like visually, you must use .link or .a  to work with links

Answer (score 0):

May this work?
browser.form(id,form_login).submit
BTW: I have seen some tips said safari only support GET mode for submit.

Answer (score -1):

I would try:
`browser.a(:href => "#").click`

Assumption - "#" is unique. may need a slash so it doesn't misinterpret the #. I used something similar when I was trying to reference a button with only a href value of `"/login"` e.g., `browser.a(:href => "/login").click`.